Handling of inverse Laplace transform of $e^{a s}$ when $a>0$
Do not know if this was asked before.
Why in V 14.1 this works
ClearAll[a, s];
InverseLaplaceTransform[Exp[a*s], s, t, Assumptions -> a > 0];
% /. a -> 1


But if I replace $a$ by $1$ in the call itself, Mathematica does not evaluate
 InverseLaplaceTransform[Exp[1*s], s, t]


Should the call InverseLaplaceTransform[Exp[a*s], s, t, Assumptions -> a > 0]; also not evaluate?
This is what happens in Maple:


This certainly is  a bug in 14.1. However, both InverseLaplaceTransform[Exp[a*s], s, t, Assumptions -> a > 0,  GenerateConditions -> True] and InverseLaplaceTransform[Exp[a*s], s, t, GenerateConditions -> True] return the inputs in 14.1 on Windows. The inverse Laplace transform of Exp[s] does not exist. Up to its definition, 1/(2*Pi*I)*  Integrate[   I*(Exp[a*s]*Exp[s*t] /. s -> 0 + I*x), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}] performs "Integrate::idiv: Integral of I E^(I (a+t) x) does not converge on {-[Infinity],[Infinity]}" and returns the input.

Consider:
LaplaceTransform[DiracDelta[a + t], t, s]

E^(a s) HeavisideTheta[-a]

Therefore, for a>0 the Laplace transform of DiracDelta[a + t] is zero. This conflicts with your assumption  E^(a s) with a>0.
